# Non-deterministic NameError: uninitialized constant on ActiveRecord model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

As titled, I'm getting a `NameError (uninitialized constant Workflow::Task)` for a model defined at `app/models/workflow/task.rb`.

I'm confident the model definition is correct because it works 90% of the time, but 10% of the time I get this name error and it crashes. I *cannot* reproduce locally, this only happens in prod, where we use an Amazon Aurora DB. Could this occur if there are issues connecting to the database or something along those lines? Any pointers are appreciated

Using rails `5.1.6.2`

Comment: I'm a bit curious - have you defined the class as `class Workflow::Task ...` or properly with explicit nesting  (`module Workflow; class Task`)? The former is bug magnet and leads to quirky issues with auto and eager loading. https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#namespace-definition

Comment: Is that model being autoloaded from a thread?

Comment: Thanks @max! The explicit module declaration fixes the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is clear from the error message that this is not a DB related issue. Put simply, Rails is not loading your model class.

You could try the following:

1. As @max commented, define your class as `module Workflow; class Task`.
2. You could manually add the file in the rails autoload paths. Put this in `config/application.rb`: `config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('app/models/workflow')`

   - However, this should not be an issue. Rails loads everything within the `app` directory.

`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, this is correct. Defining with an explicit module definition fixes the issue